Can I install Calibre without GUI?
This question was asked in 2020 by another person at another website, but since the question wasn't answered there, and even that forum is now read-only, I will ask it here:

I don't much care for the GUI of Calibre, all I care about is the ebook-convert feature of Calibre, so I was wondering if it's possible to install Calibre's command line without the additional GUI elements. Thanks.

Speaking of myself, I know about Pandoc, of course, and I use it very often. But sometimes, like when I tried to convert badly formatted .epub and .fb2 files to .html, Pandoc complained the files are corrupted and refused to process them, whereas Calibre converted them more or less successfully.

No such package, so the answer is 99% no, but you could try copying the exes and executing them while the rest is uninstalled. It'll most likely fail due to missing DLLs or other libraries though.
